# Searching with Solr, Sphinx or Lucene - ranking search results by clicks

Tags: search, lucene, solr, sphinx

I want to implement a search that will rank results higher, if previous, similar searches have led users to click on a result.

Is that possible with either Solr (Lucene) or Sphinx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, tracking of user clicks is necessary. (if the higher ranking depends on user clicks)

For "ranking higher" the results, maybe the solr-elevator function could be helpful for your needs: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/QueryElevationComponent

Probably the elevation-function is more helpful than the lucene boost function (in your case). http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/queryparsersyntax.html#Boosting%20a%20Term
Finlay it depends of the kind of implementation, i think.

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly possible with Solr (Lucene), but not really feasible. What you'd have to do is:

1. Track the clicks of users
2. Normalize the search query to group similar queries and store them
3. Reindex that into Solr

If you ask me, that sounds like a lot of work with a lot of pitfalls.

Comment: It was a client request. Personally, I don't think it makes a lot of sense. It might just be an indicator that some results (e.g. the headlines or short descriptions) are better. Still the underlying content could be completely irrelevant. That would then generate a lot of clicks, results would get ranked higher, and more users would click on presumably good results in vain.

But thank you for your assessment.

Comment: Oh, right — I didn't even think about the aspect of a self-fulfilling prophecy: The first link is irrelevant but on top, so it gets clicked. The algorithm would now tag it as relevant...

Answer (score 0):

With Sphinx you could use additional attribute clicks_count and use such query to rank clicked documents higher

```
SELECT *, clicks_count*1000 AS cc 
FROM your_index 
WHERE MATCH ("words to match") ORDER BY cc DESC;
```

to get only clicks wight into account

or

```
SELECT *, weght() + clicks_count*10000 AS cc 
FROM your_index 
WHERE MATCH ("words to match") ORDER BY cc DESC;
```

to get match weight with clicks weight into account

Of course you have update your counter 'clicks_count'.